# NSTokenField suggestion using context menu in swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, nstokenfield, nstokenfieldcell

I'm new to nstokenfield, trying to implement the UI described in developer documentation [token field guide](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/token-fields) using appkit.

I received suggestions like

[image].

I have been expecting to see the suggestion in the context menu like

[image] as in developer document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mail.app like NSTokenField for names and emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088806/mail-app-like-nstokenfield-for-names-and-emails)

Comment: No Willeke, I tried this already, which gives a result of the basic suggestion UI (above First image) . But I expect the suggestion to appear as a context menu (above second Image).

Comment: The suggestions above don't appear in a context menu. Mail shows a custom list and the image in the documentation isn't an example of a default `NSTokenField`.